# FFMpeg - Is it difficultt to use

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use ffmpeg, and have been doing a lot of experiment last 1 month.
I have not been able to get through. Is it really difficult to use FFmpeg?

My requirement is simple as below.
Can you please guide me if ffmpeg is suitable one or I have implement on my own (using codec libs available).

1. I have a webm file (having VP8 and OPUS frames)
2. I will read the encoded data and send it to remote guy
3. The remote guy will read the encoded data from socket
4. The remote guy will write it to a file (can we avoid decoding).
5. Then remote guy should be able to pay the file using ffplay or any player.

Now I will take a specific example.

1. Say I have a file small.webm, containing VP8  and OPUS frames.
2. I am reading only audio frames (OPUS) using av_read_frame api (Then checks stream index and filters audio frames only)
3. So now I have data buffer (encoded) as packet.data and encoded data buffer size as packet.size (Please correct me if wrong)
4. Here is my first doubt, everytime audio packet size is not same, why the difference. Sometimes packet size is as low as 54 bytes and sometimes it is 420 bytes. For OPUS will frame size vary from time to time?
5. Next say somehow extract a single frame (really do not know how to extract a single frame) from packet and send it to remote guy.
6. Now remote guy need to write the buffer to a file. To write the file we can use av_interleaved_write_frame or av_write_frame api. Both of them takes AVPacket as argument. Now I can have a AVPacket, set its data and size member. Then I can call av_write_frame api. But that does not work. Reason may be one should set other members in packet like ts, dts, pts etc. But I do not have such informations to set.

Can somebody help me to learn if FFmpeg is the right choice, or should I write a custom logic like parse a opus file and get frame by frame.

Comment: Why go through all this malarkey? Why not just send the file as is?

Comment: I am sending the file directly, because if remote guy does have some other software then he should be able to decode it and play it.

Comment: If somebody is voting negatively they must mention why so. I have spent lot of time in it, I could not figure it out. Before you vote negative, if you think it is easy one, then answer it. Just voting negative does not help either way.

Comment: The reason you're getting down-voted is that it's unclear why you're doing all this. You have a media file with encoded audio and video which you're unpacking and sending across the network... For what? Whoever is receiving this is going to play it, but media players already support many different formats. Your scheme doesn't appear to add anything that isn't already provided. If you're just trying to transcode on the fly you need only tell `ffmpeg` what output format you want and stream the result. Your scheme seems needlessly complicated.

Comment: Well, I should have given introduction in detail. I apologize for that. I am developing a webrtc simulator in c/c++. Simultaneously I will be running multiple Webrtc simulators. So I can not use audio/video device present in system as I am running multiple instances of simulator. I want to avoid encoding (thereby saving CPU) so want to read already encoded data. Hence I am reading from file and then sending through socket. On receive side I get it and need to decode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now remote guy need to write the buffer to a file. To write the file
>   we can use av_interleaved_write_frame or av_write_frame api. Both of
>   them takes AVPacket as argument. Now I can have a AVPacket, set its
>   data and size member. Then I can call av_write_frame api. But that
>   does not work. Reason may be one should set other members in packet
>   like ts, dts, pts etc. But I do not have such informations to set.

Yes, you do. They were in the original packet you received from the demuxer in the sender. You need to serialize all information in this packet and set each value accordingly in the receiver.

Comment: Thanks. I have thought of this idea. But does not look a robust solution. First the packets will be transported in UDP. So TX packets and RX packets will not be in synch always (packet loss, out of sequence issues). At a given instant, packet parameters for tx packet and rx packet may be different.

Comment: At this point you're basically reinventing RTP. I'd recommend you to read up on RTP and how it tries to solve these issues, and then either just use RTP or design your own custom solution based on what you've learned from RTP.